# How using humanized date can I get localized duration in JS?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, moment-timezone, date-fns

I have the following JSON object of dates:

```json
[
  {
    "date_start": "septembre 2019",
    "date_end": "septembre 2020"
  },
  {
    "date_start": "juin 2017",
    "date_end": "avril 2019"
  },
  {
    "date_start": "novembre 2015",
    "date_end": "Aujourd'hui"
  },
  {
    "date_start": "novembre 2012",
    "date_end": "février 2015"
  },
  {
    "date_start": "novembre 2011",
    "date_end": "octobre 2012"
  }
]
```

I want to convert those humanized date to a localized duration in `en_US` and `fr_FR`.

This is the expected result for `en_US`

> Duration syntax does not have to strictly be the one from this example!

```json
[
  {
    "date_start": "september 2019",
    "date_end": "september 2020",
    "duration": "1 yrs 1 mo"
  }
]
```

I am looking at [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.15.0/docs/formatDuration) and so far I have not found how to do it. (I also checked [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)).

Does anybody know how I can convert those in humanized duration? I presume this should be converted to date first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple pure JS code.

How it works:

`frStringToDate()` function converts your strings to Date objects. It checks string format first and then gets french month name and year from it. Then it translates (using `months` object) french month names to english 3-character month abbreviations to finally create a readable string for `Date` constructor.

`calculateDuration()` function subtracts two dates and "converts" the result (in milliseconds) to the `Date` object. As we know, the `new Date(0)` is `Jan 1, 1970`, so we can subtract 1970 from the year of the result `Date` object. To get the months we need to add `1` to the result of `.getMonth()` function as the months are numbered from 0. Then we can return the result string.

`getDurationFromObj()` is just for code readability

```js
const months = {
  'janvier': 'jan',
  'février': 'feb',
  'mars': 'mar',
  'avril': 'apr',
  'mai': 'may',
  'juin': 'jun',
  'juillet': 'jul',
  'août': 'aug',
  'septembre': 'sep',
  'octobre': 'oct',
  'novembre': 'nov',
  'décembre': 'dec'
}

const dates = [{
    "date_start": "septembre 2019",
    "date_end": "septembre 2020"
  },
  {
    "date_start": "juin 2017",
    "date_end": "avril 2019"
  }
]

function frStringToDate(frDateString) {
  const matched = frDateString.match(/^(\w+) (\d{4})$/)
  if (matched) {
    const frMonth = matched[1]
    const year = matched[2]

    const enMonth = months[frMonth]
    if (!enMonth) return null

    return new Date(`${enMonth}  ${year}`)
  }
  return null
}

function calculateDuration(date1, date2) {
  const durationMillis = date1 < date2 ? date2 - date1 : date1 - date2
  const durationDate = new Date(durationMillis)
  const years = durationDate.getFullYear() - 1970
  const months = durationDate.getMonth() + 1

  return `${years} yrs ${months} mo`
}

function getDurationFromObj(obj) {
  const date1 = frStringToDate(obj.date_start)
  const date2 = frStringToDate(obj.date_end)
  return calculateDuration(date1, date2)
}

dates.forEach(obj => console.log(getDurationFromObj(obj)))
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply, I am in node.js context so I don't mind using a reliable lib that weight 10mb and I doubt it will.  Also, I am worried about doing all the localization myself using that way even if I only need `fr_FR` and `en_US` for the moment. Thanks still for that reply.

Comment: It doesn't seem sensible or efficient to parse a string to create another string that is then parsed by the built–in parser, particularly when the result of the second operation is entirely implementation dependent. In Safari at least, `new Date('sep 2020')` results in an invalid Date. It would be much better to parse the month name to the equivalent month number and call the date constructor with integer values such as `new Date(2020, 8)` which is standards compliant and will produce reliable and consistent results across all implementations.